# Add or Take-away Hours or Minutes to Javascript Clock

Tags: javascript, html

I bought this clock background (and there is no support for it) and would like to know how to change the hours and minutes or at least for someone to tell me where to look.

I checked out the clock.js and other files but cannot see any settings for the adding/removing hours or minutes to the clock.

[DEMO](http://themes.smartythemes.com/ticker/index-with-single-color.html)

I understand that the clock gets the time from the users browser.

I would just like to be able to (for example) add +1 to the hour and +30 minutes.

This is the clock.js file I have

```
function initNumbers() {
    var x = 260;
    var y = 230;
    var d = 215;
    var r = [];
    for ( i = 11; i >= 0; i--) {
        var span = $('<span class="clock-number"></span>');
        span.text(((i == 0) ? 12 : i) + '');
        span.css('left', (x + (d) * Math.cos(1.57 - 30 * i * (Math.PI / 180))) + 'px');
        span.css('top', (y - (d) * Math.sin(1.57 - 30 * i * (Math.PI / 180))) + 'px');
        r.push(span);
    }
    return r;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if( jQuery('link[href*="css/dark-theme.css"]').length ) {
        var opts={plate:"#424242",marks:"#424242",label:"#424242",hours:"#424242",minutes:"#424242",seconds:"#424242"};
    } else {
        var opts={plate:"#FFFFFF",marks:"#FFFFFF",label:"#FFFFFF",hours:"#FFFFFF",minutes:"#FFFFFF",seconds:"#FFFFFF"};
    }


    SVG('canvas', '100%').clock('100%', '', opts).start();

    var n = initNumbers();
    $('#time-container .numbers-container').append(n);

    $("#canvas").everyTime("1s", function(i) {

        /* Date and time when your site starts to work */

        var c = {
            year : 2020,
            month : 7,
            day : 5,
            hh : 6,
            min : 90,
            sec : 0,
            milsec : 0
        };
        var cd = new Date();
        cd.setYear(c.year);
        cd.setMonth(c.month);
        //month start from 0
        cd.setDate(c.day);
        cd.setHours(c.hh, c.min, c.sec, c.milsec);
        //hh min sec milsec
        $('#timeleft').text(getCountDown(cd));
    });

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var delta = 0;
    var curWidth = $('#time-container').width();
    if (curWidth != null) {
        delta = curWidth - 555;
        scaleCoordinates(delta, true);
    }
    //555 , 450 , 250
    $(window).resize(function() {
        scaleCoordinates($('#time-container').width() - 555, false);
    });
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

});
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Some code would be usefull

Comment: There is nothing in JavaScript itself that lets you do what you are looking for, but there was a library written that may help you.  It's kind of a dirty hack, but for a simple late like that one is prolly OK: 

http://schickling.me/override-system-time-in-javascript/

Comment: in clock.js see the two lines after `// Set a date and get the milliseconds`. That is the date that you should alter.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thanks for taking your time to comment and help me out, I tried editing it but it does not change anything :( . I think that is for the countdown timer that I don't use.

Comment: in clock.js line 107 change the var `c = {...}` and add more or less days/hours/min

Comment: I should have put it as an answer instead of a comment. hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Adjusting the countdown timer

Considering this is a **countdown clock**, check the **lines 105-124** of the javascript file `clock.js`

Change this part:

```
var c = {
    year : 2017,
    month : 5,
    day : 8,
    hh : 00,
    min : 00,
    sec : 0,
    milsec : 0
};
```

To add **+1 hour** and **+30 minutes** as you mentioned, change it to:

```
var c = {
    year : 2017,
    month : 5,
    day : 8,
    hh : 1,
    min : 30,
    sec : 0,
    milsec : 0
};
```

## Adjusting the clock

The clock part is kinda trickier. I had to enhance a bit your `svg.clock.min.js` to accept a new parameter to adjust the time components (hours, minutes and seconds).

You can check the modified code bellow:

```
    SVG.Clock = function(a, c, d, timeModifiers) {

    var b, d;
    c = c || {};
    for (b in c) d[b] = c[b];

    this.timeModifiers = timeModifiers

    this.full = {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0
    };
    this.time = {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0
    };
    this.constructor.call(this, SVG.create("svg"));
    this.viewbox(0, 0, 100, 100);
    this.size(a, a);
    this.plate = this.ellipse(99.5, 99.5).move(.25, .25).fill("none").stroke({
        color: d.plate,
        opacity: 1,
        width: .3
    });
    this.plate += this.ellipse(97, 97).move(1.5, 1.5).fill("none").stroke({
        color: d.plate,
        opacity: 1,
        width: .15
    });
    this.plate += this.ellipse(93, 93).move(3.5, 3.5).fill("none").stroke({
        color: d.plate,
        opacity: 1,
        width: .15
    });
    this.plate += this.ellipse(3.5, 3.5).move(48.25, 48.25).fill(d.plate);
    for (b = 11; 0 <= b; b--) this.rect(.5, 2.8).move(49.75, 1.7).fill(d.marks).rotate(30 * b, 50, 50);
    for (b = 59; 0 <= b; b--) 0 != b % 5 && this.rect(.2, 2).move(49.9, 1.7).fill(d.marks).rotate(6 * b, 50, 50);
    this.hours = this.rect(.6, 35).move(49.7, 20).fill(d.hours);
    this.minutes = this.rect(.6, 46).move(49.7, 9).fill(d.minutes);
    this.seconds = this.group().move(50.65,
        43).add(this.rect(.2, 50).move(-.75, -37.5).fill(d.seconds));
    this.plate += this.ellipse(2, 2).move(49, 49).fill("#999ca6");
    this.update(0)
};

SVG.Clock.prototype = new SVG.Container;

SVG.extend(SVG.Clock, {
    start: function() {
        var a = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            a.update()
        }, 1E3);
        return this
    },
    update: function(a) {

        var c = new Date;

        null == a && (a = 900);

        var timeModifiers = this.timeModifiers || {hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0};

        var hours = c.getHours() + (timeModifiers.hours || 0),
            minutes = c.getMinutes() + (timeModifiers.minutes || 0),
            seconds = c.getSeconds() + (timeModifiers.seconds || 0);

        this.setHours(hours, minutes)
            .setMinutes(minutes, a)
            .setSeconds(seconds, a);

        return this
    },
    setHours: function(a, c) {
        this.time.hours = a;
        this.hours.rotate((a + c / 60) % 12 * 30, 50, 50);
        return this
    },
    setMinutes: function(a, c) {
        if (a == this.time.minutes) return this;
        this.time.minutes = a;
        0 == a && this.full.minutes++;
        var b = 360 * this.full.minutes + 6 * a;
        c ? this.minutes.animate(c, SVG.easing.elastic).rotate(b, 50, 50) : this.minutes.rotate(b, 50, 50);
        return this
    },
    setSeconds: function(a, c) {
        this.time.seconds = a;
        0 == a && this.full.seconds++;
        var b = 360 * this.full.seconds + 6 * a;
        c ? this.seconds.animate(c, SVG.easing.elastic).rotate(b, 50, 50) : this.seconds.rotate(b, 50, 50);
        return this
    }
});

SVG.extend(SVG.Container, {
    clock: function(a, b, c, timeModifiers) {
        return this.put(new SVG.Clock(a, b, c, timeModifiers))
    }
});
```

There is a new attribute called `timeModifiers` that will be used in the `update` function (**line 58**) to allow incrementing / decrementing the time.

To render the clock with an additional 30 minutes for example, use the following syntax:

```
var timeModifier = {
    seconds: 0, // NUMBER OF SECONDS TO ADD/SUBTRACT
    minutes: 30, // NUMBER OF MINUTES TO ADD/SUBTRACT
    hours: 0 // NUMBER OF HOURS TO ADD/SUBTRACT
};

SVG('canvas', '100%').clock('100%', '', opts, timeModifier).start();
```

Keep in mind that the current date (based on the client's computer) is always used on this component, as you can check in **line 60**, inside the `update` function.

You can also check the enhanced component in the following [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/graargh/1484bc3697bea7c289f99b6a0ec1c16e)

Comment: I think that is for the countdown timer that I don't use. I understand that the clock gets the time from the users browser.

I would just like to be able to (for example) add +1 to the hour and +30 minutes.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just input the number 1 in the HH and 30 in the MIN using the example i just posted and you will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Tested, does not work. I made sure that the .js updated the changes but I still think that is for the countdown time only and not for the current (browser) time.

Comment: Update: Even if I takeout the entire function getCountDown(cdate) my clock still works. So I'm not even using that function at all. As I said, that is for the countdown that I am not using. I am using the current time.

Comment: I added my clock.js (see above) it doesnt even have the getCountDown function and the clock still works.

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks for your existence! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 options for you, one I can test with succesfully and the other I can only guess:

**1st way (tested locally)**

You can override the constructor of `Date` function. `new Date()` returns the current local date. With this overriding it will return current local date +90 minutes. Put this code before any script reference in the document and see the magic:

```
var bind = Function.bind;
var unbind = bind.bind(bind);

function instantiate(constructor, args) {
    return new (unbind(constructor, null).apply(null, args));
}

Date = function (Date) {
    MyDate.prototype = Date.prototype;

    return MyDate;

    function MyDate() {
        var date = instantiate(Date, arguments);
        date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 90);
        return date;
    }
}(Date);
```

**2nd way (not tested)**

I added this line between somewhere in `svg.clock.min.js`:

```
c=new Date(c.setMinutes(c.getMinutes() + 90));
```

Now here is the final content of `svg.clock.min.js`:

```
SVG.Clock=function(a,c,d){ var b,d;c=c||{};for(b in c)d[b]=c[b];this.full={hours:0,minutes:0,seconds:0};this.time={hours:0,minutes:0,seconds:0};this.constructor.call(this,SVG.create("svg"));this.viewbox(0,0,100,100);this.size(a,a);this.plate=this.ellipse(99.5,99.5).move(.25,.25).fill("none").stroke({color:d.plate,opacity:1,width:.3});this.plate+=this.ellipse(97,97).move(1.5,1.5).fill("none").stroke({color:d.plate,
opacity:1,width:.15});this.plate+=this.ellipse(93,93).move(3.5,3.5).fill("none").stroke({color:d.plate,opacity:1,width:.15});this.plate+=this.ellipse(3.5,3.5).move(48.25,48.25).fill(d.plate);for(b=11;0<=b;b--)this.rect(.5,2.8).move(49.75,1.7).fill(d.marks).rotate(30*b,50,50);for(b=59;0<=b;b--)0!=b%5&&this.rect(.2,2).move(49.9,1.7).fill(d.marks).rotate(6*b,50,50);this.hours=this.rect(.6,35).move(49.7,20).fill(d.hours);this.minutes=this.rect(.6,46).move(49.7,9).fill(d.minutes);this.seconds=this.group().move(50.65,
43).add(this.rect(.2,50).move(-.75,-37.5).fill(d.seconds));this.plate+=this.ellipse(2,2).move(49,49).fill("#999ca6");this.update(0)};SVG.Clock.prototype=new SVG.Container;
SVG.extend(SVG.Clock,{start:function(){var a=this;setInterval(function(){a.update()},1E3);return this},update:function(a){var c=new Date;c=new Date(c.setMinutes(c.getMinutes() + 90));null==a&&(a=900);this.setHours(c.getHours(),c.getMinutes()).setMinutes(c.getMinutes(),a).setSeconds(c.getSeconds(),a);return this},setHours:function(a,c){this.time.hours=a;this.hours.rotate((a+c/60)%12*30,50,50);return this},setMinutes:function(a,c){if(a==this.time.minutes)return this;this.time.minutes=a;0==a&&this.full.minutes++;var b=360*this.full.minutes+6*a;
c?this.minutes.animate(c,SVG.easing.elastic).rotate(b,50,50):this.minutes.rotate(b,50,50);return this},setSeconds:function(a,c){this.time.seconds=a;0==a&&this.full.seconds++;var b=360*this.full.seconds+6*a;c?this.seconds.animate(c,SVG.easing.elastic).rotate(b,50,50):this.seconds.rotate(b,50,50);return this}});SVG.extend(SVG.Container,{clock:function(a, b, c){return this.put(new SVG.Clock(a, b, c))}});
```

Comment: I added my clock.js (see above) it doesnt even have the getCountDown function and the clock still works.

Comment: @compcobalt sorry, I had misunderstood at first. I've just updated my answer, see if it works now.